# Move files to another directory which are older than a date

Tags: unix, files, find, copy

I am looking for a solution to move files that are year older from today. My log partition is getting full, but I can not remove them. They are needed for a long long time. Anyway one solution I came up with is:

```
find /sourcedirectory -mtime 365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Would this work? Asking because of the "*-mtime 365*" would this move the files that are year older from today to a new location?

Thank you!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're almost right. `-mtime 365` will be all files that are exactly 365 days old. You want the ones that are 365 days old or more, which means adding a `+` before the number like this `-mtime +365`.

You may also be interested in the `-maxdepth 1` flag, which prevents you from moving items in sub directories.

If you want to be sure that you are only moving files, not directories, add `-type f` to the line.

At the end of the line we add `\;` so that `find` knows that's the end of the command we are executing.

So the line should be:

```
find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

To be on the safe side, start by just doing a ls -l instead of mv - that way you can check in advance that you're getting exactly the files you want, before re-running it with mv, like this:

```
find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `mtime` is ***Modification*** time (which sounds like what you probably want -- most of the time it is). If these logs are read/referred to often you might want to use `-atime` (last access time).

Comment: What does the backslash at the end of this line do?

Comment: @BenLiyanage The backslash is an escape character for the semicolon that follows. The semicolon means the end of the `exec` statement. See the man page for `find`.

Answer (score 5):

**Be careful when using the above solutions, I used them and ended up moving all files in all subfolders!!!!**

This command moves all files in /source directory and all subfolders under source directory:

```
find /sourcedirectory -mtime +365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Instead, use option -maxdepth 1 for only files in /sourcedirectory

```
find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: The highest rated answer contains this note, and suggests using `-type f`. Did you mean this instead to mean that the subfolders do get moved but the contents of them remain in the subfolders instead of getting moved out of them or...?

Comment: no, I mean that 'find' will find all files in /sourcedirectory and all subfolders within that /sourcedirectory, which I didn't think about at the time.  The '-maxdepth 1' restricts the 'find' to only /sourcedirectory

Comment: BTW, I would have had this as just a comment to the highest rated answer, which was a good answer, but I don't have the reputation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command, and specify that you only find for files, not directory, and the file is older than one year

```
find /sourcedirectory -type f -mtime +365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: Why should he use `rm`? Your command deletes both the log files and  possibly the destination directory.

Comment: Ops, my mistake, I think @mYzk want to remove this files.
Edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command with atime if the files are accessed often

```
find /sourcedirectory -type f -atime +365 -exec mv -t /destinationdirectory {} +;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /sourcedirectory/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Correct would be remove ending forward slash from `/sourcedirectory/`

```
$ find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: In my tests, I was not able to replicate the `find: missing argument` error, however I do agree that dropping the trailing slash from `/sourcedirectory` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pipe to the `while` command like this:

```
find /sourcedirectory/ -mtime +365 -print | while read line ; do mv $line /destination/directory/ ; done
```